# Java Spring JDBC template problem

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-mvc

```
public List<Weather> getWeather(int cityId, int days) {
    logger.info("days: " + days);
    return getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT weather.id, cities.name, weather.date, weather.degree " +
                                        "FROM weather JOIN cities ON weather.city_id = cities.id " +
                                        "WHERE weather.city_id = ? AND weather.date BETWEEN now()::date AND (now() + '? days')::date",
                                        this.w_mapper, cityId, days);
}
```

error :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT weather.id, cities.name, weather.date, weather.degree FROM weather JOIN cities ON weather.city_id = cities.id WHERE weather.city_id = ? AND weather.date BETWEEN now()::date AND (now() + '? days')::date]; The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.
```

it works with :

```
public List<Weather> getWeather(int cityId, int days) {
    logger.info("days: " + days);
    return getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT weather.id, cities.name, weather.date, weather.degree " +
                                        "FROM weather JOIN cities ON weather.city_id = cities.id " +
                                        "WHERE weather.city_id = ? AND weather.date = now()::date",
                                        this.w_mapper, cityId);
}
```

**so the problem is when im using two ? marks in my query.
how can i make it work to with 2 ? marks???**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably in this part:

```
'? days'
```

The question mark is inside a literal string and so it is not recognized by the sql parser. <del>You could try to rewrite it using the string concatenation operator, although I'm not 100% sure that is valid syntax in this case.</del>

According to [this page on the postgres wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL) you should be able to simply omit the string 'days', since adding a date and an integer is interpreted as adding the specified number of days.

```
BETWEEN now()::date AND now()::date + ?
```

Comment: nope didnt work .. operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone + integer

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite the SQL part

```
AND weather.date BETWEEN now()::date AND (now() + '? days')::date
```

as

```
AND weather.date BETWEEN now()::date AND ?
```

and set it with a fullworthy `java.sql.Date` value instead of `days`.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
Date endDate = new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
// ...
```

(once again, it's `java.sql.Date`, not `java.util.Date`!)

Comment: yeah but they i have to do whole new method or alot of code..when psql already has builint function for adding days. is that really my only solution. or we could make my thing work also?

Comment: It's not allowed to use preparedstatement placeholders `?` as part of SQL strings/functions. It has got to be the whole value already. Just create a helper method to minimize the code duplication, if that's your concrete problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you only have 1 param (ie a ?) in the first sql statement, but you are passing in two args.  Spring doesn't know what to do with the second arg.